# Sitecore page editor add here button not appearing for specific user

Tags: sitecore8

I am getting the below error from browser console whenever i tried to click on add component at the sitecore page editing ribbon bar, and this add here button doesn't appear on the placeholders. Also this is happening for a specific content author user alone and not for other users, Please help on the same

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'parent' of undefined or null reference
Chrome.js (298,9)
: {"stack":"TypeError: Unable to get property 'parent' of undefined or null reference \n   at getChildChromes (http://wpois037/sitecore/shell/Applications/Page%20Modes/Chrome.js:298:9) \n   at renderings (http://wpois037/sitecore/shell/Applications/Page%20Modes/ChromeTypes/PlaceholderChromeType.js:504:5) \n   at activate (http://wpois037/sitecore/shell/Applications/Page%20Modes/PlaceholderInsertion.js:21:5) \n   at onShow (http://wpois037/sitecore/shell/Applications/Page%20Modes/ChromeTypes/PlaceholderChromeType.js:485:5) \n   at Anonymous function (http://wpois037/sitecore/shell/Applications/Page%20Modes/DesignManager.js:11:7) \n   at each (http://wpois037/sitecore/shell/Controls/Lib/jQuery/jquery-1.6.4.min.js:2:12790) \n   at insertionStart (http://wpois037/sitecore/shell/Applications/Page%20Modes/DesignManager.js:10:5) \n   at showRenderingTargets (http://wpois037/sitecore/shell/Applications/Page%20Modes/PageEditor.js:431:5) \n   at showRenderingTargets (http://wpois037/sitecore/shell/Applications/Page%20M

Answer (score 0):

It seems the issues is with having slick carousel js plugin into the site. As sitecore edit mode is causing html overlap with the slick html generation.

Got the solution in another post to use slick carousel with infinite property to false.